# Automated process to update employee list

Tags: sharepoint-server

My organization is transitioning from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2019 (on-prem version). We currently have a list that we use for an employee directory, but we update the list manually. With the move to Sharepoint 2019, we want to be able to automate the process and link to the Oracle server we use for HR content. However, our organization does not want to use Active Directory. Is there a way to have an automated process that will pull from Oracle to a Sharepoint list, via an API? Is there a profile area in Sharepoint (that is not Active Directory) that we can use to store the data?  Or, can we easily import content into a Sharepoint list from Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can have following possible approach here:

**Approach 1 - Use SharePoint User Profile**

If your Oracle and Active Directory does have same number of user then you can create one console application or script to sync data from Oracle to SharePoint User Profile and you can schedule it in Task scheduler to automatize it.

**Approach 2 - Use SharePoint List**

Here you still need to create console application/script to sync data from Oracle to SharePoint List and you can schedule it in task scheduler to automatize it

Below are some helper links based on above:

- [Update User Profile using Power Shell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/12/update-user-profile-properties-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html)
- [User Profile Service Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/user-profile-service-overview)
- [SharePoint List CRUD Operation using PowerShell](https://digiboek.net/2013/11/12/sharepoint-list-crud-operation-using-powershell-management/)